# Python data aggregation ("Countifs" function in Excel)

Tags: python, excel, data-analysis, aggregation, countif

Long-time Excel user turned new Python user here. I have the following data frame of product IDs:

```
productID              sales
6976849                194,518,557             
11197085               277,387,647
70689391               197,511,925
70827164               242,995,691
70942756               1,529,319,200
```

(It doesn't look pretty in the interface, but in Python I've managed to get this into a dataframe with a column for ID and a column for Sales.)

Each product ID has a total number of sales.

What I need is a count of how many products have over 200,000,000 sales, as well as how many products have under 200,000,000 sales.

Bucket                 Total count
Over 200,000,000        x
Under 200,000,000       y

In Excel I would do this with a quick Countif function, but I'm not sure how that works in Python.

I'm having a surprisingly difficult time finding how to do this--can anyone point me in the right direction? Even just the names of the functions, so that I can read about them, would be useful!

Thank you!!

Comment: Use [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: As a beginner, I would not personally recommend using pandas dataframes until you get fairly familiar with the language itself. They are quite powerful, but your application is quite simple, and doesn't strictly need their flexibility. Saving your file as a csv, then reading the file and parsing the text would be a good exercise in learning to work with files, string conversions, and handling simple data structures (like lists, etc...)

Comment: You're right @Aaron. Can you answer to the question using `csv` module, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and `value_counts`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
over, under = df['sales'].gt(200000000).value_counts().tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> over
3

>>> under
2
```

Step by step:

```
# Display your data after load file
>>> df
   productID       sales
0    6976849   194518557
1   11197085   277387647
2   70689391   197511925
3   70827164   242995691
4   70942756  1529319200

# Select the column 'sales'
>>> df['sales']
0     194518557
1     277387647
2     197511925
3     242995691
4    1529319200
Name: sales, dtype: int64

# Sales are greater than 200000000? (IF part of COUNTIF)
>>> df['sales'].gt(200000000)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: sales, dtype: bool

# Count True (over) and False (under) (COUNT part of COUNTIF)
>>> df['sales'].gt(200000000).value_counts()
True     3
False    2
Name: sales, dtype: int64

# Convert to list
>>> df['sales'].gt(200000000).value_counts().tolist()
[3, 2]

# Set variables over / under
>>> over, under = df['sales'].gt(200000000).value_counts().tolist()
```

**Update**

> I should also add that there are 100 million rows in the dataset, and I will need more buckets, something like Over 500 million between 200 million and 500 million between 100 million and 200 million under 100 million Can you tell me how I would go about setting the buckets?

Use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html):

```
df['buckets'] = pd.cut(df['sales'], right=False, ordered=True,
                       bins=[0, 100e6, 200e6, 500e6, np.inf],
                       labels=['under 100M', '100-200M',
                               '200-500M', 'over 500M'])
```

```
>>> df
   productID       sales    buckets
0    6976849   194518557   100-200M
1   11197085   277387647   200-500M
2   70689391   197511925   100-200M
3   70827164   242995691   200-500M
4   70942756  1529319200  over 500M

>>> df.value_counts('buckets', sort=False)
buckets
under 100M    0
100-200M      2
200-500M      2
over 500M     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you! I should also add that there are 100 million rows in the dataset, and I will need more buckets, something like

Over 500 million
between 200 million and 500 million
between 100 million and 200 million
under 100 million

Can you tell me how I would go about setting the buckets?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of very powerful libraries out there to help you get things done quickly, but you mention that you're just starting out, so I would recommend sticking to just python itself as a learning experience.

Excel can save files to "CSV" which is a very simple text file format. CSV files are typically just a line by line representation of each row in your spreadsheet, with columns separated by commas. A very simple solution to your question could be to read such a file line by line, determine if the number of sales is greater or less than a given number, and add one to the appropriate group.

Starting out with reading the file is fairly simple. Reading files in code is a little bit different to what you may be used to, but it is very simple and is almost always the same between different programming languages. First you "open" the file, which basically asks the Operating system for access. The OS will determine if you should have access or not, and if so, will give you access to what amounts to a cursor that can scan through the file. This "cursor" is often referred to as the "file handle" or in python simply a "file object".

```py
file_obj = open("data.csv", "r")  #"r" for reading mode (instead of write)
```

Once we have the handle, we can call its `read` method to read part or all of the file. Passing a number will tell how many characters (a new line and some other invisible codes count as a character) to read, or in python you can pass no parameters, and it will read the whole file. Because we opened the file in text mode (default) we will get a regular string.

```py
file_contents = file_obj.read()
```

Now that we have copied the contents of the file into a string, we can close the file and tell the OS that we're done with it.

```py
file_obj.close()
```

You may often see this a little differently in python using the `with` context in order to clean up the code a little, and make sure the file always gets closed:

```py
with open("data.csv", "r") as file_obj:
    file_contents = file_obj.read()
```

Now you have a big long string containing the entire CSV file. We want to be able to go row by row, so we have to separate the string into parts anywhere we find a new-line character. Python strings have a convenient way of doing this using the `str.split` method:

```py
file_lines = file_contents.split("\n") #split the string into a list of strings by splitting on \n chars
```

With this list now we'll create a loop to read each line, and determine if the product had more or less than 200,000,000 sales. To do this we will have to find the appropriate section of each line, convert it to a number, and use an `if` statement to decide what to do with it. The simplest form of python loop is to go over each item in a simple list of items: `for line in file_lines:`. Now on each iteration inside the loop, the `line` variable will be filled with whatever was in that line of the file. As long as the csv file has no blank lines, and no headers we pretty much only have to find the second value (as separated by a comma), and convert it to a number. Here we'll use the `str.split` method again, to split the string at the comma, and convert the second item to an integer (remember python uses 0 based indexing, so the 2nd item will be index 1). From here we can add some logic to determine if we should count one for under or over 200 million.

```py
over = 0
under = 0
for line in file_lines:
    line_items = line.split(",")
    sales = int(line_items[1])
    if sales > 200000000:
        over = over + 1
    else:
        under = under + 1
```

Finally here's a more advanced version after reading your comment on needing more "buckets"

```py
buckets = [0] * 8 #list of 8 buckets each starting at 0
bucket_edges = [0, 1e6, 2e6, 5e6, 1e7, 2e7, 5e7, 1e8, 2e8] #an even more advanced version would find the max and min of the sales figures, and dynamically calculate the bucket edges
with open("data.csv") as f: #"r" mode is actually the default
    sales = [] #an empty list
    for line in f: #a default behavior of file handles is to read line-by-line in for loops
        line = line.strip() #remove leading and trailing whitespace
        if not line: #an empty string will act like "False"
            continue #advance to the next loop iteration
        sales.append(int(line.split(",")[1])) #combine a few operations in a single line, and build up a list of sales figures
for sale in sales:
    for i in range(len(buckets)):
        if bucket_edges[i] <= sale < bucket_edges[i+1]:
            buckets[i] += 1
for i in range(len(buckets)):
    print(bucket_edges[i], "to", bucket_edges[i+1], ":", buckets[i])
```

Comment: Nice explanation, for that +1. But you have to use `csv` module (this is a module of standard library). Probably, you can use `bisect` (bisect_left) and `collections` (defaultdict) modules too. If you don't use any modules from the standard library, Python wouldn't be as useful.

Answer (score 0):

If using `convtools` and having xlsx file converted to csv, then a short answer is:

```py
# pip install convtools
from convtools import conversion as c

converter = c.aggregate({
    "below_200": c.ReduceFuncs.Count(where=c.item("sales") < 200000000),
    "above_200": c.ReduceFuncs.Count(where=c.item("sales") >= 200000000),
}).gen_converter()
results = converter(list_of_dicts)
```

A longer one:

```py
import csv

# pip install convtools
from convtools import conversion as c

buckets = [
    (None, 200000000),
    (200000000, 220000000),
    (220000000, 240000000),
    (220000000, None),
]


def bucket_to_condition(bucket, input_):
    conditions = []
    left, right = bucket
    if left is not None:
        conditions.append(input_ >= left)
    if right is not None:
        conditions.append(input_ < right)
    if not conditions:
        return {}
    return {
        "where": c.and_(*conditions) if len(conditions) > 1 else conditions[0]
    }


with open("input_data.csv", "w") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    # skip header (assuming it's known)
    next(header)

    converter = (
        c.iter(
            {
                "productID": c.item(0),
                "sales": c.item(1).as_type(int),
            }
        )
        .pipe(
            c.aggregate(
                {
                    f"{bucket}": c.ReduceFuncs.Count(
                        **bucket_to_condition(bucket, c.item("sales")),
                    )
                    for bucket in buckets
                }
            )
        )
        .gen_converter()
    )
    results = converter(reader)
```